# How to filter zero in array php?

Tags: php

I tried get count zero in array with array_filter, my code is:

```
$arr=[1,2,0,3,4,5,0];
$countzero=count(
    array_filter($arr,function($x){
    if($x==0){
        return $x;
    }})
);

echo $countzero;
```

result is

```
0
```

expected result is

```
2
```

if condition `if($x>0)`, result is `5`, but why `if($x==0)` result is `0` ?, thanks for help

Comment: `array_filter` expects the callback to return `true` or `false` to accept or reject the current row of the array you passed to it. Your code tests for zero but then returns ZERO which is interpreted as FALSE! So no rows are selected! ;-/ Just return the result of the test in the callback and it works as you expect. i.e `$countzero=count(
   array_filter($arr, function($x) {
     return ($x == 0);
}));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this a different way:

```
echo array_count_values($arr)[0];
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Rq3qN

The issue with current implementation is that `0` is FALSE so:

> If the callback function returns true, the current value from array is returned into the result array.

Could do:

```
$arr=[1,2,0,3,4,5,0];
$countzero=count(
    array_filter($arr,function($x){
    if($x==0){
        return 1;
    }})
);
echo $countzero;
```

which gives a TRUE for each `$x==0`.

Comment: Thanks its work.. I think 0 and false different value

Comment: @IwanKurniawan 0 is evaluated as false unless using strict comparison, see https://3v4l.org/Z41X9

Answer (score 0):

With php 7.4, you can write it more concisely:

```
$countzero = count(array_filter($arr, fn($x) => $x));
```

Indeed, `array_filter()` expects a callback which returns a boolean. And since `0` is converted to `false` and any other integer is converted to `true`, it will give the expected result.

Comment: Its mean 0 == false ? sometimes i get confused about this

Comment: @IwanKurniawan It means that converting an int to a bool results to `false` if it's `0`, and `true` for all other cases, so `(bool) 0 === false` and `(bool) 13 === true`